# if $\gcd(f,g)=1$ in $R[X]$, then $\gcd(f,g)=1$ in $K[X]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, polynomials

Let $R$ is an integral domain and $K$ its field of fractions

Question: if $\gcd(f,g)=1$ in $R[X]$, then  $\gcd(f,g)=1$ in $K[X]$?

Note that $R$ is not necessary a GCD domain.
$\gcd(f,g)=1$ means that the only common divisors of $f$ and $g$ are units of $R[X]$ (resp. $K[X]$).

Comment: Did you look for Gauss' lemma and its consequences?

Comment: R is not a GCD domain ( moreover R[X] is not necessary a GL (Gauss lemma) domain)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try $R=\Bbb{Q}[t^2,t^3]$ and $t$ a root of both $f$ and $g$

Comment: But $X-t$ will be a common divisor of $f$ and $g$ in $R[X]$ !

Comment: $X-t$ is not in $R[X]$

Comment: if $t$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$, then $Fr(R)=R$!

Comment: $t$ is not algebraic over $\Bbb{Q}$, it is a ring of polynomials. $f=t^2X-t^3,g=X^2-t^2$

Comment: ok. it's clear thanks.